# How to make different firefox windows recognizable by VirtuaWin?

Tags: windows, firefox, virtual-desktop, virtuawin

I want to automatically move certain windows of firefox based on `<criteria>*` to certain virtual desktops.

VirtuaWin supports this but it needs

> `Class Name:   MozillaWindowClass`
>
> `Window Name:  How to make different firefox windows recognizable by VirtuaWin? - Super User - Mozilla Firefox`
>
> `Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`

None of them gives me anything useful to differentiate between my different windows.

I'm using different profiles in firefox if that helps me.

Answer (score 1):

I realized I can change the firefox executable to anything.

Since I was already using different profiles, and so different instances anyways,

I've made hardlinks to `firefox.exe` as

`firefox_1.exe`,

`firefox_2.exe`

… and launch them as

`firefox_1.exe -p 1`

`firefox_2.exe -p 2`

… So now it shows

`Process Name:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox_1.exe` &

`Process Name:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox_2.exe`

which satisfies the criteria of differentiating between two windows.